# Android traking the faster thread ends whitout frozen appl

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar, simultaneous

I’m a android developer beginner, so I want to put 2 threads running simultaneously in background (or not), one is for testing Wifi connectivity, and another for timeout respond with progress bar( or another thing for showing that application is not dead),  in “main” I want to waiting, if wifi testing is faster than timeout, send user for one page, if timeout ran out, send user for different page.
I already have to threads, one doing timeout+progressBar and other checking connectivity, my problem is who to waiting for the fast thread that end, I tried with a loop checking for thread.isalive(), but in that way progress bar doesn’t show, and the application frozen until some thread ends… =\

any help?! Sorry my bad english...

public void startProgress() {

```
    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                final int value = i;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progress.setProgress(value);
                    }
                });
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.error_menu);
            //finish();
        }
    };
    Thread th1 = new Thread(r1);
    th1.start();

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        // Setup the run() method that is called when the background thread
        // is started.
        public void run() {
            // Do you background thread process here...
            // Checking if WIFI is ON and IF URL is Reachable
            if(isOnline()){
                String URL_STR="http://10.0.1.2/ShopList_for_app.php";
                try
                {
                    URL url = new URL(URL_STR);
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(7000); // This is time limit if the connection time limit
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200){ 
                        setContentView(R.layout.menu1);
                        //finish();//return;
                    }else{
                        //finish();//return;
                    }
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //finish();//return;
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //finish();//return;
                }
            }else{
                //finish();//return;
            }
        }
    };
    Thread th2 = new Thread(r2);
    th2.start();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "..Correu todas as Threads..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    while(true){
        if(th2.isAlive()){
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"checking...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{              
            th1.interrupt();
            setContentView(R.layout.menu1);
            break;
        }           
            if(th1.isAlive()){
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"checking...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            th2.interrupt();
            setContentView(R.layout.error_menu);
            break;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: can you post some code? That way we may be able to see the problem in the code or suggestion you a solution much faster...